# Runtime.availableProcessors: what is it going to return?

Tags: java

The javadoc for `Runtime.availableProcessors()` in Java 1.6 is delightfully unspecific. Is it looking just at the hardware configuration, or also at the load? Is it smart enough to avoid being fooled by hyperthreading? Does it respect a limited set of processors via the linux `taskset` command?

I can add one datapoint of my own: on a computer here with 12 cores and hyperthreading, Runtime.availableProcessors() indeed returns 24, which is not a good number to use in deciding how many threads to try to run. The machine was clearly not dead-idle, so it also can't have been looking at load in any effective way.

Comment: The fact that the documentation explicitly mentions that its value may change makes it unlikely that it is only looking at the hardware configuration. My guess is that it returns the number of Java threads that can be run in parallel.

Comment: Oracle/Sun have written 'optimistic' doc in the past. I agree about the implication, but I am fishing for facts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it always gives you the total number of available CPUs even those not available for scheduling.  I have a library which uses this fact to find reserved cpus.  I read the /proc/cpuinfo and the default thread affinity of the process to work out what is available.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows, [GetSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used and `dwNumberOfProcessors` from the returned `SYSTEM_INFO` structure.

This can be seen from `void os::win32::initialize_system_info()` and `int os::active_processor_count()` in `os_windows.cpp` of the OpenJDK source code.

`dwNumberOfProcessors`, from the MSDN documentation says that it reports 'The number of logical processors in the current group', which means that hyperthreading will increase the number of CPUs reported.

On Linux, `os::active_processor_count()` uses [sysconf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf):

```
int os::active_processor_count() {
  // Linux doesn't yet have a (official) notion of processor sets,
  // so just return the number of online processors.
  int online_cpus = ::sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
  assert(online_cpus > 0 && online_cpus <= processor_count(), "sanity check");
  return online_cpus;
}
```

Where `_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN` documentation says 'The number of processors currently online (available).'  This is not affected by the affinity of the process, and is also affected by hyperthreading.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Sun Bug 6673124](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6673124):

> The code for `active_processor_count`, used by `Runtime.availableProcessors()` is as follows:

```
int os::active_processor_count() {
  int online_cpus = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
  pid_t pid = getpid();
  psetid_t pset = PS_NONE;
  // Are we running in a processor set?
  if (pset_bind(PS_QUERY, P_PID, pid, &pset) == 0) {
    if (pset != PS_NONE) {
      uint_t pset_cpus;
      // Query number of cpus in processor set
      if (pset_info(pset, NULL, &pset_cpus, NULL) == 0) {
    assert(pset_cpus > 0 && pset_cpus <= online_cpus, "sanity check");
    _processors_online = pset_cpus;
    return pset_cpus;
      }
    }
  }
  // Otherwise return number of online cpus
  return online_cpus;
}
```

This particular code may be Solaris-specific.  But I would imagine that the behavior would be at least somewhat similar on other platforms.