# How to make Java application use all CPU groups

Tags: java, cpu-usage, numa

I am running a java application on Intel(R) Xeon(R) machine which has 72 CPUs (with Hyperthreading on). Since, Microsoft groups CPUs into two groups if there are more than 64 CPUs, the java application uses only 1 group (or in other words 36 CPUs). See the snapshots below for the grouping and CPU usage details. As we can see, the java application is using 36 CPUs at capacity but not able to use other CPUs.

[image]

[image]

I added +UseNUMA in JVM parameters but it did not work. Does anyone know of JVM option to make it use all CPU groups?

The windows server machine has 72 CPUs after hyperthreading. Windows, by default, groups the CPUs into two memory nodes if number of CPUs are more than 64 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405503(VS.85).aspx). Java application uses only 1 nodes and thus not using the computer at capacity. I enabled node-interleaving but it didn't help either. So, my question is if there is a way to span Java application over multiple memory nodes.

Comment: Just curious: What does Java show for this code `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();` on the machine?

Comment: Not sure if that helps, but maybe you could try other JVMs, like http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/java8/ (I *believe* you can download IBM java for free, worst case, you might have to register an IBM id).

Comment: Michael, The available number of processors is shown to be 36 when I run Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()

Comment: Hyperthreading may not count. You only have 36 physical cores.

Comment: @Gaurav Then that particular JVM at that particular invocation only knows about 36 "logical" cpu cores.

Comment: Note: The Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() call takes Hyperthreading into consideration.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis It seems you are correct: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9423537/2161954

Comment: based on http://area.autodesk.com/blogs/max-station/n268-how-many-cores-does-3ds-max-support# I'd say it's simply not possible unless java has support for windows' specific mechanism. The numa option is only memory related (prefers the local memory).

Comment: Also https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9589087d-9036-4b39-bfce-059aed7b2abf/windows-allow-only-a-maximum-of-36-logical-processors-per-process-out-of-total-of-72-?forum=winserver8gen and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6942632